# Find paths that exceed SharePoint's 400 character limit

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

We recently migrated to SharePoint online and have found that a few of our paths are getting corrupt files because they exceed the 400 character limit set by SharePoint . I am only an admin of our specific site and not a global admin of our SharePoint Tenant, so trying to use SharePoint's PowerShell integration does not work. I also tried viewing in explorer view and running PowerShell from there to find anything -gt 400, but there is a windows limitation of only being able to find paths up to 248 characters before getting an error. Has anyone ran into this issue or know of any workarounds?

I have tried using the module `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` with PowerShell, but get forbidden error because I am not a global admin. I also tried recursively looking in Windows Explorer view but get an error.

Here is the error when trying to do it in windows explorer view:

> Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and
>   the directory name must be less than 248 characters

Comment: win10 can enable native support for long[er] file paths. also, the Robocopy util can get the whole name for you - set it to simply do `/L` to NOT change anything, just `List` what it would do. then you can parse the log file for your long files ... and Robocopy can move those files elsewhere so that you can use a shorter path.

Answer (score 0):

did You consider using SharePoint online CSOM? You could use this nuget -> [SharePointPnP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)

with this You could implement any kind of application (like a console app) and get all the folders, files and files in all folders and get their name, or path or whatever is needed and check if it is longer then 400 characters. (please remember that additional columns like FileServerRelativeUrl needs to be loaded in context)

```
try
{
    string siteUrl = "SiteURL";
    AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
    using (ClientContext context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LibName");
        context.Load(list);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection folderCol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
        foreach (Folder f in folderCol)
        {
            context.Load(f.Files);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            FileCollection innerFileCol = f.Files;
            foreach (File file in innerFileCol)
            {
                //var x = file.Name;
                // ToDo other logic here 
            }
        }
        FileCollection fileCol = list.RootFolder.Files;
        foreach (File file in fileCol)
        {
            //var x = file.Name;
            // ToDo other logic here 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log error
    throw;
}
```

I hope it will be of any help :)